# Function not writing to .xls correctly . Python 2.7.1

Tags: python, string, function, export-to-excel

When I check my Excel file it only writes one line of data which is the last input.

```
def Table(fn,fe):

       for fseq in fn:
              count=0
              for k in fseq:
                     if k=='G' or k=='C':
                            count=count+1
              percentage=(float(count)/len(fseq))*100
              fin=open(fe,'w')
              table=str(fseq)+'\t'+str(count)+'\t'+str(percentage)+'\n'
              fin.write(table)
       return fe



tablist=["AAUG","GCGA","AGCG","TCGA"]
fout=Table(tablist, 'abc.xls')
```

It is supposed to output this:

```
   AAUG    1   25.0
   GCGA    3   75.0
   AGCG    3   75.0
   TCGA    2   50.0
```

Instead, my output looks like this:

```
   TCGA    2   50.0
```

and return the name of file being written.

Why is it only writing data for the last element of the string?

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Why not use [openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/wiki/Home)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Created an empty String and then added each value of the table to it was created during the iteration in the for loop. Wrote the string the .xls file

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is looping over the strings, not the characters of each string. Try this:

```
   for k in fn:
       for c in k:
          if c=='G' or c=='C':
                 count=count+1
```

(The else: is not necessary.)

You will also need to move your file writing code inside of the outer loop in order to get your report correct (but move the open above the outer loop).

Comment: it writes 9 into the excel file i tried it after i realized that k was each string in the list

Comment: You also need to rearrange the code that outputs to the file. It needs to open once at the top of your function and write once every time around the outer for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
if k=='G' or k=='C':
```

None of the members of your list will ever match this condition. Hence, your `count` remains at `0`.

You probably want to loop over the characters in your string.